# Join MariaDB table on JSON array to text field

Tags: json, join, mariadb

Table `crons` has a JSON field called `surveys` which contains a JSON array of UUIDs like:

```json
[
  "65f42c322ea442099612cad251be1dac",
  "43788fe207b143dc9eac4da38c036af6"
]
```

### Table1 (crons):

```sql
CREATE TABLE "crons" (
  "id" int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  "depts" longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin,
  "surveys" longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
  CONSTRAINT "CONSTRAINT_1" CHECK (((`depts` is null) or json_valid(`depts`))),
  CONSTRAINT "CONSTRAINT_2" CHECK (((`surveys` is null) or json_valid(`surveys`))),
  CONSTRAINT "crons_chk_1" CHECK (json_valid(`depts`)),
  CONSTRAINT "crons_chk_2" CHECK (json_valid(`surveys`))
)
```

### Table2 (surveys):

Table `surveys` contains the field `survey_uuid` which is a varchar string.

```sql
CREATE TABLE "surveys" (
  "id" int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  "survey_uuid" varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
  UNIQUE KEY "surveys_survey_uuid_uindex" ("survey_uuid"),
  CONSTRAINT "survey_json" CHECK (((`survey_json` is null) or json_valid(`survey_json`)))
)
```

I need to return all the rows where `surveys.survey_uuid` (varchar) is contained in `crons.surveys` (JSON array)

### Attempt:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM crons c
         JOIN
     surveys s
    ON (JSON_SEARCH(c.surveys, 'one', s.survey_uuid) IS NOT NULL)
WHERE start_date < NOW()
  AND end_date > NOW()
  AND JSON_SEARCH(c.depts, 'one', 'sales') IS NOT NULL
```

**note**: MariaDB stores JSON as longtext but all the JSON functions work. I have verified that `JSON_SEARCH(depts, 'one', 'sales') IS NOT NULL` is a valid way to search a JSON field array.

The one thing you can't do in MariaDB is `CAST(something AS JSON)` but you can `CAST(jsonfield AS char)`

Comment: MariaDB has diverged from original MySQL enough that we should now consider it a different database implementation. It's not compatible with MySQL. I have updated the title and tags for this question to make it clear you're using MariaDB, not MySQL. That will help get the attention of readers who can give you the best answers.

Comment: Provide some sample data as INSERT INTO for both tables and desired output for this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to search for all the rows in `surveys` that have at least one matching row in `crons`, the following SQL should work:

```
SELECT s.id, s.survey_uuid, c.id, c.depts, c.surveys
  FROM surveys s JOIN crons c
  ON (JSON_SEARCH(c.surveys, 'all', s.survey_uuid) IS NOT NULL)
  ORDER BY s.id;
```

If you want to include rows in `surveys` that have no rows in `crons`, use a `LEFT JOIN`.

---

With the following data:

```
MariaDB [test]> select * from crons;
+----+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | depts        | surveys                                                      |
+----+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | {"d1": "d1"} | ["B8606CA2F4000004"]                                         |
|  2 | {"d2": "d2"} | ["B8606CA2F4000005"]                                         |
|  3 | {"d3": "d3"} | ["B8606CA2F4000004", "B8606CA2F4000006"]                     |
|  4 | {"d4": "d4"} | ["B8606CA2F4000004", "B8606CA2F4000005", "B8606CA2F4000007"] |
|  5 | {"d5": "d5"} | [""]                                                         |
|  6 | {"d6": "d6"} | [""]                                                         |
+----+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select * from surveys;
+----+------------------+
| id | survey_uuid      |
+----+------------------+
|  5 | B8606CA2F4000004 |
|  6 | B8606CA2F4000005 |
|  7 | B8606CA2F4000006 |
|  8 | B8606CA2F4000007 |
|  9 | B8606CA2F4000008 |
| 10 | B8606CA2F4000009 |
| 11 | B8606CA2F400000A |
+----+------------------+
7 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

The result for the query is:

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT s.id, s.survey_uuid, c.id, c.depts, c.surveys FROM surveys s JOIN crons c ON (JSON_SEARCH(c.surveys, 'all', s.survey_uuid) IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY s.id;
+----+------------------+----+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | survey_uuid      | id | depts        | surveys                                                      |
+----+------------------+----+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|  5 | B8606CA2F4000004 |  1 | {"d1": "d1"} | ["B8606CA2F4000004"]                                         |
|  5 | B8606CA2F4000004 |  3 | {"d3": "d3"} | ["B8606CA2F4000004", "B8606CA2F4000006"]                     |
|  5 | B8606CA2F4000004 |  4 | {"d4": "d4"} | ["B8606CA2F4000004", "B8606CA2F4000005", "B8606CA2F4000007"] |
|  6 | B8606CA2F4000005 |  2 | {"d2": "d2"} | ["B8606CA2F4000005"]                                         |
|  6 | B8606CA2F4000005 |  4 | {"d4": "d4"} | ["B8606CA2F4000004", "B8606CA2F4000005", "B8606CA2F4000007"] |
|  7 | B8606CA2F4000006 |  3 | {"d3": "d3"} | ["B8606CA2F4000004", "B8606CA2F4000006"]                     |
|  8 | B8606CA2F4000007 |  4 | {"d4": "d4"} | ["B8606CA2F4000004", "B8606CA2F4000005", "B8606CA2F4000007"] |
+----+------------------+----+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
7 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```